# Upload Video to GCS from GCE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm struggling finding out a way to upload video files to GCS from my GCE. I think [this doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/getstarted) is the most relevant one but the example is supposed to be run on GAE, which has a much more straightforward authentication process, not GCE. My question is how to authenticate GCE to access GCS and upload objects with Python client APIs. I have no problem doing so with `gsutil`, but I want to use Python APIs directly. The docs from Google are very fragmented and kinda confusing for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: this doc as well: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials

Comment: @Kamran the second link is really helpful to me. I used the same way but finally found a formal documentation with detailed explanations. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I just noticed the first link that I posted was wrong. sorry for that. this is the link:  https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/python-guide#authorization